# Illegal state: Transaction for catalog table write operation 'pg_database' not found in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Before dropping a database, first I want to prevent new connections and then drop the existing connections. However, I'm stuck at the first step:

```
ysqlsh (11.2-YB-2.1.1.0-b0)

yugabyte=# SELECT * FROM pg_database;
          datname           | datdba | encoding | datcollate |  datctype   | datistemplate | datallowconn | datconnlimit | datlastsysoid | datfrozenxid | datminmxid | dattablespace |               datacl
----------------------------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------
 template1                  |     10 |        6 | C          | en_US.UTF-8 | t             | t            |           -1 |             0 |            0 |          1 |          1663 | {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
 template0                  |     10 |        6 | C          | en_US.UTF-8 | t             | f            |           -1 |             0 |            0 |          1 |          1663 | {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
 postgres                   |     10 |        6 | C          | en_US.UTF-8 | f             | t            |           -1 |             0 |            0 |          1 |          1663 |
 yugabyte                   |     10 |        6 | C          | en_US.UTF-8 | f             | t            |           -1 |             0 |            0 |          1 |          1663 |
 system_platform            |     10 |        6 | C          | en_US.UTF-8 | f             | t            |           -1 |             0 |            0 |          1 |          1663 |
 test_1650530283_52506      |  12462 |        6 | C          | en_US.UTF-8 | f             | t            |           -1 |             0 |            0 |          1 |          1663 |
(6 rows)

yugabyte=# UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn=false WHERE datname = 'test_1650530283_52506';
ERROR:  Illegal state: Transaction for catalog table write operation 'pg_database' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described behavior is not a bug. Everything works as expected. It is not recommended to change system tables manually. If it absolutely necessary for some reason user should set the `yb_non_ddl_txn_for_sys_tables_allowed` GUC variable to `true`. But user will do this on its own risk.

BTW to disallow connection to DB it is better to use this query instead of changing system table manually:

```
ALTER DATABASE db WITH ALLOW_CONNECTIONS false;
```